# Transforming a linestring table to trajectories on the fly

Tags: postgis, trajectory

I have the following code:

```
tracks AS
(SELECT 
    imei,
    st_setsrid(ST_MakeLine(points_geom ORDER BY time_created),4326) AS track from 
    subset_cr  
    GROUP BY imei
)
```

Is there any way I can transform these linestring tracks into trajectories on the fly since I do not have write permissions in the db?

I want to use time_created as the measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reconstruct measured points from your dataset and collect them into `LINESTRING M`s:

```
SELECT
  imei,
  ST_SetSRID(
    ST_MakeLine(
      ST_MakePointM(ST_X(points_geom), ST_Y(points_geom), time_created::BIGINT)
      ORDER BY time_created
    ),
    4326
  ) AS trajectory_geom
FROM
  subset_cr
GROUP BY
  imei
;
```